# Why is my zero-cost alternative to RefCell not the standard way of achieving interior mutability?

Tags: rust, lifetime, interior-mutability

I've been thinking about why interior mutability in Rust in most cases requires runtime checks (e.g. `RefCell`). It looks like I've found a safe alternative without a runtime cost. I've called the type `SafeCell` (mainly because it is a safe wrapper around `UnsafeCell`), and it allows you to apply any function to the wrapped value without the risk of having the reference escape:

```rust
struct SafeCell<T> {
    inner: UnsafeCell<T>,
}

impl<T> SafeCell<T> {
    pub fn new(value: T) -> Self {
        Self {
            inner: UnsafeCell::new(value),
        }
    }

    pub fn apply<R, F>(&self, fun: F) -> R
    where
        F: FnOnce(&mut T) -> R,
    {
        // Reference below has a lifetime of the current scope, so if
        // user tries to save it somewhere, borrow checker will catch this.
        let reference: &mut T = unsafe { &mut *self.inner.get() };
        fun(reference)
    }
}
```

This type can be used for interior mutability like this:

```rust
pub struct MySet {
    set: HashSet<i32>,
    unique_lookups: SafeCell<HashSet<i32>>,
}

impl MySet {
    pub fn contains(&self, value: i32) -> bool {
        self.unique_lookups.apply(|lookups| lookups.insert(value));
        self.set.contains(value)
    }

    pub fn unique_lookups_count(&self) -> usize {
        self.unique_lookups.apply(|lookups| lookups.len())
    }
}
```

Or in conjunction with `Rc`:

```rust
fn foo(rc: Rc<SafeCell<String>>) {
    rc.apply(|string| {
        if string.starts_with("hello") {
            string.push_str(", world!")
        }
        println!("{}", string);
    });
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=65b894c742f80cf59553726f13276953)

1. Are there any safety/soundness issues with this type?
2. If not, why is a type like this not a standard way of achieving interior mutability? It looks like it is as usable as `RefCell` while providing static lifetime checks as opposed to runtime checks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is nothing in your API stopping a user from calling `apply` again in the closure provided to `apply`. This allows there to be multiple simultaneous mutable references to the same data, which is undefined behavior.

```rust
let x = SafeCell::new(0);
x.apply(|y| {
    x.apply(|z| {
        // `y` and `z` are now both mutable references to the same data
        // UB!
        *y = 1;
        *z = 2;
    })
});
x.apply(|y| println!("x: {}", y));
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c91732926e906495e4351bcd95b1b248)

Miri correctly calls this out when it sees the second mutable reference being made.

```
error: Undefined Behavior: not granting access to tag <untagged> because incompatible item is protected: [Unique for <1651> (call 1230)]
  --> src/main.rs:20:42
   |
20 |         let reference: &mut T = unsafe { &mut *self.inner.get() };
   |                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not granting access to tag <untagged> because incompatible item is protected: [Unique for <1651> (call 1230)]
   |
```

Comment: For an example of a data race using this idea, check out [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=306e982d59df3c88384a2d1d131cfff0).